# Problema em atualização de um UpdatePanel

Tags: webforms

Tenho uma página que contém diversos gráficos. Usamos o Google charts para criá-los. Os gráficos estão organizados em dashboards.

## Descrição da página:

Na página contém um `UpdatePanel` responsável pelos botões dos dashboards `uppDashboards` dentro deste contém um `asp:Repeater` com cada link para o dashboard, que são criados dinamicamente.

Abaixo do `uppDashboards` contém um `UpdatePanel` responsável por gerar todos os gráficos, o `uppScripts`. desntro destes contém 2 literais, um responsável pela inclusão dos scripts do google e o `ltrDashboard` responsável por conter todos os scripts de carregamento dos gráficos da tela. A cada update no `uppScripts`uma nova id é gerada para as funções que geram os gráficos.
Segue um exemplo do código gerado na `ltrDashboard`:

```
<div class='gridster'>
    <ul>
        <li id='8|IndicadorGrafico' data-col='5' data-row='5' data-sizex='5' data-sizey='5' data-max-sizex='5'
            data-max-sizey='5'>
            <div class="item fundoGraficos">
                <div id="divGraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569" class="divGraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569"
                    style="width: 560px; height: 500px; margin: auto; padding-top: 9px; "></div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
                            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(
                                GraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569);

                            function GraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569() {
                                var chartDiv = document.getElementById(
                                    'divGraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569');
                                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                    ['Data de Emissão - Mês', 'Valor'],
                                    ['Janeiro de 2018', 122477.5976],
                                    ['Fevereiro de 2018', 107240.4000],
                                    ['Março de 2018', 127834.0200],
                                    ['Abril de 2018', 112301.9750],
                                    ['Maio de 2018', 85482.4250],
                                    ['Junho de 2018', 120004.3600],
                                    ['Julho de 2018', 130099.3300],
                                    ['Agosto de 2018', 109626.7750],
                                    ['Setembro de 2018', 97912.2000],
                                    ['Outubro de 2018', 101668.0250],
                                    ['Novembro de 2018', 10062.8776],
                                    ['Dezembro de 2018', 74.6100]
                                ]);
                                var options = {
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                    hAxis: {
                                        titleTextStyle: {
                                            color: '#495057'
                                        },
                                        textStyle: {
                                            color: '#495057'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    vAxis: {
                                        titleTextStyle: {
                                            color: '#495057'
                                        },
                                        textStyle: {
                                            color: '#495057'
                                        },
                                        format: 'R$ #,##0.00'
                                    },
                                    chartArea: {
                                        left: '20 %',
                                        top: '15 %',
                                        right: '5 %',
                                        bottom: '12 %'
                                    },
                                    animation: {
                                        duration: 1500,
                                        startup: true
                                    },
                                    width: 560,
                                    height: 500,
                                    title: 'Teste2',
                                    titleTextStyle: {
                                        color: '#495057',
                                        fontSize: '18'
                                    },
                                    legend: {
                                        position: 'none'
                                    },
                                    bar: {
                                        groupWidth: '90%'
                                    }
                                };
                                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartDiv);
                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            };
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <div Class="item-edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ContentPlaceHolder1_AppContentPlaceHolder_uppScripts','EditarIndicador#8')"><i
                        Class="far fa-pencil-alt"></i></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## Descrição do processo:

Ao alterar o dashboard as classes css dos botões são alteradas. Um novo script é gerado na `ltrDashboard`. é feito um update no `uppDashboard` e no `uppScripts`

Ao criar um novo dashboard um novo item é inserido no repeater e a função para alterar o dashboard é chamada com o código do novo item.

## Descrição do problema:

Ao entrar na página pela primeira vez todo o comportamento de troca de dashboard está funcionando perfeitamente. quando clica em um dashboard diferente o script da `ltrDashboard` é gerado com uma nova id, executado e os gráficos são gerados corretamente.

Ao adicionar um dashboard o ultimo Script gerado é "congelado" e fica sempre chamando com a id antiga. Explicando de outra forma:

> Acessar a página

Script 111 é gerado na `ltrDashboard`
Script 111 é chamado
Graficos gerados

> Clicar no segundo Dashboard

Script 112 é gerado na `ltrDashboard`
Script 112 é chamado
Graficos gerados

> Clicar para voltar ao primeiro Dashboard

Script 113 é gerado na `ltrDashboard`
Script 113 é chamado
Graficos gerados

> Adicionar Dashboard

Script 114 é gerado na `ltrDashboard`
Script 113 é chamado e dá erro no console
Graficos com erro

> Alterar para o primeiro Dashboard

Script 115 é gerado na `ltrDashboard`
Script 113 é chamado e dá erro no console
Graficos com erro

> A partir disso só volta a chamar o script atualizando após recarregar a página

O erro ocorre na linha do script:

```
var chartDiv = document.getElementById('divGraficoColuna58710331423957543044827774055569');
```

Pois esse elemento não existe mais.

Algo muito estranho é que acessando a guia Elements do Chrome a ID está atualizada, porém quando acesso o documento pela guia Sources a ID antiga está lá. Isso ocorre em todos os Browsers.

Não consigo identificar o porque está executando um código antigo, sendo que o novo é o que consta na guia Elements. Alguém já passou por algum problema parecido na hora de trabalhar com os UpdatePanels?

## EDIT

É possível fazer este código de uma forma diferente e que não ocorra o mesmo problema com os Update Panels?